# taking picture with FileProvider onActivityResult bitmap null

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, bitmap

I'm trying to follow https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics to get original image size, but I got null on the bitmap

```
    lateinit var currentPhotoPath: String

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun createImageFile(): File {
        // Create an image file name
        val timeStamp: String = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Date())
        val storageDir: File = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)!!
        return File.createTempFile(
            "JPEG_${timeStamp}_", /* prefix */
            ".jpg", /* suffix */
            storageDir /* directory */
        ).apply {
            // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
            currentPhotoPath = absolutePath
        }
    }

    private fun dispatchTakePictureIntent(numbers: Int) {
        Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).also { takePictureIntent ->
            // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
            takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager)?.also {
                // Create the File where the photo should go
                val photoFile: File? = try {
                    createImageFile()
                } catch (ex: IOException) {
                    // Error occurred while creating the File
                    null
                }
                // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                photoFile?.also {
                    val photoURI: Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                        this,
                        BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                        it
                    )
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI)
                    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, numbers)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

onActivityResult :

```
val bitmap = data?.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap
strImageTabungan1 = ConvertBase64().getStringImage(bitmap)
img_1.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
```

I can open the camera activity, but when trying to get the result, it returns

```
**java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=888, result=-1, data=Intent {  }} to activity {com.example.abcdef/com.example.abcdef.form.ExampleActivity}: kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.graphics.Bitmap**
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: There is no thumbnail bitmap available using putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT).

Comment: Use BitmapFactory.loadFromFile() to create a bitmap.

Comment: where to put "BitmapFactory.loadFromFile()" ? @blackapps

Comment: In onActivityResult. Or where you want.

Comment: @blackapps but there is no .loadFromFile()

Comment: The name is slightly different. Android Studio will tell you the right one.